# Meteor Iron-Routing at refresh

Tags: meteor, routes

I use the iron - routing and the routs works fine. But if I try to refresh the page with the browsers button it seems that the second / callback function in the routing is not fired and the page goes blank. The function only fires when the url changes which is not the case at refresh. Is there any solution ?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for `beforeunload` event?

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I think I have missunderstood something in the router. I try to set a session var in the data part (after my db call) which works sometimes and sometimes not (Async ?, hardcoded - it works). I workaround it with not to use session vars because I have other possibilities now when using iron routing. So the problem is no longer actual.

Comment: No need to set a session in the data. The session is global for the client regardless of where set. The data hook goes to the template, like for helpers.